# Django db raw MySQL execute

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a model and custom manager

model

```
class VideoDescription(models.Model):
    title_eng = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    title_ru = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date_start = models.DateField()
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_poster_path)
    genre = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length=10, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

objects = VideoDescriptionManager()

class VideoDescriptionManager(models.Manager):
def get_video_by_genre(self, genre):
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''select m.id, m.title_eng, m.title_ru, m.slug, m.rating, m.pub_date_start,
        m.poster, m.genre, m.description, COUNT(*) from main_app_videodescription m
                        where genre like "%%%s%%";''', [genre])
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(id=row[0], title_eng=row[1], title_ru=row[2], slug=row[3], rating=row[4],
                           pub_date_start=row[5], poster=row[6], genre=row[7], description=row[8])
            p.num_responses = row[9]
            result_list.append(p)
        return result_list
```

And i've got a error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Google talking me change [genre] to (genre,) in a raw sql query but it doesn't help.
What can i do to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using raw sql here? You can use [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains) for the filter on `genre`. I don't understand why you have a `COUNT(*)` when you have no join or groupby.

Comment: @Alasdair Because i don't know about `contains`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite does not use `%s` for parameters, it uses `?`.

But either with sqlite or another db, you can't use the parameter substitution to insert a param in the middle of a string. You need to build up the string separately, and then insert it using the parameters. So:

```
param = "%{}%".format(genre)
cursor.execute('''select m.id, m.title_eng, m.title_ru, m.slug, m.rating, m.pub_date_start,
                  m.poster, m.genre, m.description, COUNT(*) from main_app_videodescription m
                        where genre like ?;''', [param])
```

Note that using `.format` removes the need to double-escape the percents.

Comment: It's a Django cursor -- I thought it used `%s` for placeholders even if you are using sqlite.

Comment: Now i've got an error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`